# How can I freely apply an image-texture/normal-map to an Image Texture Node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

[image]
I baked some normal maps, but the newest one doesn´t appear in the selection menue of the node. How can I gain free access to it?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure what are you talking about, Did you make that Normal 2 texture? That is the **newest one** or not? If yes, it is already in your image texture node and you just need to put it into color input of normal node

Comment: I made a third Normal texture that I can´t access like in other cases. I just found out you can simply drag Textures from outside into blender

Comment: Or add a new *Image Texture* node and use the *Open* button. You can open images also in the *Image Editor* (in the *Texture Paint* and *Rendering* workspace). After you've opened the image it will appear in the drop-down list of the *Image Texture* node.